# URL string compare not working in php

Tags: php, regex

I have this URL "https://www.example.com/thymus_vulgaris?tag=Oil&page=2" 
where I get  **/thymus_vulgaris?tag=Oil&page=2** from **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']** in php
and I have also saved the same URL in database that I am getting in a variable 
$abc = **/thymus_vulgaris?tag=Oil&page=2**
you can see both URL URI is same I am writing this code.
but comparison is not working please see the screenshot value for better understand

```
foreach ($redirects as $redirectlink) { 
                        if('/thymus_vulgaris?tag=Oil&page=2' == $redirectlink['title']){
                                die;
                            }
                        }
```

if I do print_r($redirects) I got this array results see below

```
Array
```

(

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [title] => /thymus_vulgaris?tag=Oil&page=2
        [url] => essential-oils
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [title] => /products/diffusers
        [url] => diffusers
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [title] => /essential-oils/Essential-Oil-Kits/sleep_and_breathe
        [url] => essential-oils
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [title] => /Solum%20Lux%20Telum
        [url] => essential-oils
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [title] => /organic-boswellia-serrata
        [url] => essential-oils
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [title] => /faqs
        [url] => FAQ
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [title] => /clearance/refurbished-replacement-bottles/amp
        [url] => accessories/bottles-and-caps/amp
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [title] => /refurbished-replacement-bottles/amp
        [url] => accessories/bottles-and-caps/amp
    )
```

)

if you see first array value is same as request $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] value.
Can anybody help me quickly?

Comment: How do you know comparison is not working?  `die("it worked");` maybe?

Comment: I tried what you posted here and it worked for me.  I thought maybe some character was messing it up (/ ? &) but all is ok.  Are you certain you do not have any HTML entities that appear as `&` but are actually `&amp;`  anywhere?  Add `var_dump($redirectlink['title']);` just before the if.

Answer (score 1):

I guess probably some invisible char, because of which `==` resulting `false`,

**For example :  [DEMO](https://eval.in/1039985)**

```
$ php -r '$f1="foo"; $f2="foo\0"; echo $f1.PHP_EOL; echo $f2.PHP_EOL; var_dump($f1); var_dump($f2); var_dump($f1==$f2);'
foo
foo
string(3) "foo"
string(4) "foo"
bool(false)
```

As you can see above, `$f1` and `$f2` both are not equal, but looks like same.

***Output :***

[image]